# Firefox Add-on SDK and Cross-domain

Tags: jquery, cross-domain, firefox-addon-sdk

I would like to access comment section on youtube with Firefox extension. Since the comment section is in iframe, and it is located on other site(plus.googleapis.com) I need to enable cross-domain function.

I did that by including cross-domain-content in package.json:

```
{
  "name": "testfirefoxextension",
  "title": "testFirefoxExtension",
  "id": "id removed",
  "description": "nike z youtubu v zvezi",
  "author": "kv1dr",
  "license": "MPL 2.0",
  "version": "0.1",
  "permissions": {
    "cross-domain-content": ["http://www.youtube.com", "https://plus.googleapis.com/"]
  }
}
```

and just in case, in `lib/main.js` I added both youtube.com and googleapis.com to include section. This is full content of the `lib/main.js`:

```
// Import the page-mod API
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
// Import the self API
var self = require("sdk/self");

// Create a page mod
// It will run a script whenever a "youtube.com" URL is loaded
// The script replaces the page contents with a message
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: ["*.youtube.com","*.googleapis.com"],
  contentScriptFile: [self.data.url("jquery-2.1.1.min.js"), self.data.url("youtube.js")]
});
```

in youtube.js I have `alert($("#comments-test-iframe").html());` just to test, if the cross-domain script is working, but when the comments are loading, the script shows empty message, but when the comments are loaded, the script shows [undefined], instead of the content of the comments section. Why? And how to get the iframe content?

Comment: Can we see more of youtube.js? Could it be because you're missing the final `/` in `"http://www.youtube.com"`. Could it be because youtube is at `https`?

Comment: That's all from yotube.js. I didn't add anything else, because even this don't work. And yes, I tried also with adding slash to the end of the YouTube link, and I am testing this extension on Non-SSL(http) page of YouTube, but it still don't work.

Comment: "when the comments are loaded, the script shows [undefined]." Where's the code that waits for the comments to load?

Comment: Well, I don't know why, but even when I do on load event on #coments-test-iframe, id doesn't do anything, but with the "developer tools" on F12 key, I can see this div is there. Nevermind, I tried with another div, and it suddenly worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was the problem with `youtube.js` code. I don't know why, but I couldn't access #comments-test-frame element, so I tried with another div, that's inside of iframe, and it worked.